# Android show Activity as a dialog, and cannot be cancelled

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, android-alertdialog

In my android app, I show an Activity as a dialog. When the user touches somewhere outside the dialog, it is cancelled automatically.

Is it possible to remove that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `AlertDialog.Bulider`, this can be accomplished like:

```
yourDialog.setCancelable(false);
```